# How to know stream is xlsx or xls or csv?

Tags: .net, excel

I know file extension can know it, e.g:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetExcelType("xxx.xls")); // Xls
    Console.WriteLine(GetExcelType("xxx.xlsx")); // Xlsx
    Console.WriteLine(GetExcelType("xxx.csv")); // csv
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
internal enum ExcelType
{
    Xlsx,Xls,Csv
}

internal ExcelType GetExcelType(string path)
{
    var e = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
    switch (Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant())
    {
        case ".csv":
            return ExcelType.Csv;
        case ".xlsx":
            return ExcelType.Xlsx;
        case ".xls":
            return ExcelType.Xls;
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only allow file extension xlsx,xls,csv");
    } 
}
```

but if input is Stream, it don't have file extension to check.

Comment: Where is this “stream” coming from?

Comment: @DourHighArch Memory or File or Download from url etc.

Comment: As you've noticed, file extensions are part of files and not of streams. If you're creating data in memory you have to know the format before you put it into a stream. You need to read file extensions before you turn files into a stream. If you're using a url you have to determine the data type before you turn it into a stream. Etc.

Comment: @DourHighArch thanks, it looks like no way to check in stream, could u answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read few bytes of the stream and guess the format.

```
var buffer = new byte[512];
stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
var magic = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);
switch (magic)
{
  // Old office format (can be any office file)
  case 0xE011CFD0: return ExcelType.Xls;
  // New office format (can be any ZIP archive)
  case 0x04034B50: return ExcelType.Xlsx;
}
// Text file (the bigger the buffer, the more probability)
// Won't work for UTF-16 encoding, but it's rare
if (buffer.All(b => b >= ' ' || b == '\n' || b == '\r' || b == '\t')) return ExcelType.Csv;
throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

Of course, this is just a guess and does not guarantee that the stream is indeed in expected format, but file extension does not provide any guarantees as well. The only way to ensure that the input is in correct format is to fully parse it and handle any exceptions which can occur. But this guess is enough to choose which parser to try.

Also this consumes the bytes from the stream, so you need to account for that if you are going to use the stream after the check. If `stream.CanSeek == true`, you can just set `stream.Position = 0`. If it isn't, you could copy the original stream into a `MemoryStream` which can seek (but this could take a lot of time); or implement your own stream which will provide the contents of `buffer` before reading the original stream; or just ensure that you use the buffer before you read the rest of the stream.